# (React) How do you pass in functions to components that are wrapped in a variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

If you look at the image link, you can find two const variable, signUpBtn and signInBtn. I am passing in these two variables to Signup component as props.

The problem is I have an action creator(function) called navigatePage that I have to pass into SignupBtn components inside the two const variables. However, the function doesn't get passed in properly and I can't seem to figure it out. Please refer to the code from this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7odUd.png). Thanks!!
    import React from "react";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";

```
import Signup from "./Signup";
import SignupEmail from "./SignupEmail";
import SignupBtn from "./SignupBtn";
import { signup, signin, signupEmail } from "./helpers";
import { navigateSignUpPages } from "../../../actions/Signup";

const SignUpRoot = ({ currentPage, navigatePage }) => {
    const signUpBtn = (
        <React.Fragment>
            <SignupBtn
                SignWith="Sign up with Email"
                onClick={() => console.log("clicked")}
            />
            <SignupBtn SignWith="Sign up with Github" />
            <SignupBtn SignWith="Sign up with Facebook" />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
    console.log("test", signUpBtn);

    const signInBtn = (
        <React.Fragment>
            <SignupBtn SignWith="Sign in with Email" />
            <SignupBtn SignWith="Sign in with Github" />
            <SignupBtn SignWith="Sign in with Facebook" />
            <SignupBtn SignWith="Sign in with Google" />
            <SignupBtn SignWith="Sign in with Twitter" />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
    return (
        <div className="signup-wrapper">
            {currentPage === "SignUpEmail" && (
                <SignupEmail
                    title={signupEmail["title"]}
                    text={signupEmail["text"]}
                    theme={signupEmail["theme"]}
                />
            )}
            {currentPage === "SignIn" && (
                <Signup
                    title={signin["title"]}
                    text={signin["text"]}
                    theme={signin["theme"]}
                    linkMsg={signin["linkMsg"]}
                    link={signin["link"]}
                    linkState={signin["linkState"]}
                    signBtn={signInBtn}
                />
            )}
            {currentPage === "SignUp" && (
                <Signup
                    title={signup["title"]}
                    text={signup["text"]}
                    theme={signup["theme"]}
                    linkMsg={signup["linkMsg"]}
                    link={signup["link"]}
                    linkState={signup["linkState"]}
                    signBtn={signUpBtn}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    currentPage: state.Signup.navigateSignupPage
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    navigatePage: page => dispatch(navigateSignUpPages(page))
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignUpRoot);
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code that you have written?

Comment: You have provided only the view, not the backend code. Also add the code snippet directly in question so people can copy that and try out. Images don't allow copy

Comment: Sorry! I edited my post with my code

Comment: Well yes, you don't pass in or use any `navigatePage` argument in the creation of `signUpBtn` or `signInBtn`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few major problems with the code provided.

You shouldn't have if-statements inline, instead you should be creating a component to handle that.

IE:

```
const SomeComponent = ({ someValue }) => {
  if (someValue === 1) return <ComponentOne />
  if (someValue === 2) return <ComponentTwo />
}

<SomeComponent someValue=1 />
```

In your case you should be handling that in your SignUpRoot

Secondly, if you are using React + Redux as you claim, there should be no need to be passing around the currentPage variable as that is available already as a prop via the React/Redux router.

Restructuring how you are handling things will greatly simply things and will reduce the issues you are seeing.

Comment: `You shouldn't have if-statements inline, instead you should be creating a component to handle that.` I disagree, there is nothing wrong with conditional JSX.